# Logarithmic xaxis not working if pointStart property is not given

Tags: highcharts

If i am giving yaxis type as 'logarithmic' , then the chart is working but when i am giving axis type as ' logarithmic' then not working.

but it is working when i set  (pointStart: 1) in series. Please suggest.

here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stxskdyL/1/

```
$(function () {
 $('#container').highcharts({

    title: {
        text: 'Logarithmic axis demo'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        type: 'logarithmic'
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        minorTickInterval: 0.1
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br />',
        pointFormat: 'x = {point.x}, y = {point.y}'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512],
    }]
});

var a =  $('#container').highcharts();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `pointStart` highcharts is throwing this error:

> Highcharts error #10: [www.highcharts.com/errors/10](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/10)

Why?  Your data has no x-values:

```
data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512],
```

Be default Highcharts will assign it auto-incrementing x values starting at 0.  The first point then becomes:

```
[0,1]
```

And you can't log(0):

```
> Math.log(0)
  -Infinity
```

With `pointStart` that auto-incrementing starts at 1 and all is well.

Comment: Can you please tell me that how to update the pointstart after chart creation. i am getting the pointStart from backend. so i need to update after creation. please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. Removing any tickInterval/minorTickInterval settings for the axis fixed it for me.